# How to call variables from different events together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn how to call variables from different events.

I have 2 inputs, without a submit button. So, the way I get the value is by using the [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event.

**My Code:**

```js
function myPhone() {
  $("#phone").keyup(function() {
    var phone = $(this).val();
  });
  return phone;
}

function myEmail() {
  $("#email").keyup(function() {
    var email = $(this).val();
  });
  return email;
}

function myValidation() {
  var myPhone2 = myPhone();
  var myEmail2 = myEmail();

  alert(myPhone2 + " - " + myEmail2);
}

myValidation();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="phone">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
```

**Explanation Behind My Code:**

First, I create a function called `myPhone()` where it saves the value of what has been inserted by the user based on keyup. I do the same for email and create a function `myEmail()`.

Now, I created another function named `myValidation` and tried to call the values I get in `myPhone()` and `myEmail()` and then I try to display the values in an alert box.

But, this is not working for me. I can see that it will alert upon page load, and show undefined, which makes sense for me.

But why is it not tracking the keyup event? And why is the 2 variables not getting called in? Have i done it wrongly? Can someone please guide me on this with explanation?

Comment: You're trying to alert both values even if the event isn't yet triggered. You should `1. Attach the event first` `2. Create a global access to the email and phone variables, could also be an object` `3. Run myValidation() after both events are triggered, adding a flag to do so;` `4. Alert the values from the global scope`

Comment: @AbanaClara Thanks for that explanation, but can you show me how to go about doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

If you want to get the value of your input, you can use `$( "#email" ).val()` at anytime in your code.

Comment: @FlorentDescroix But if I put it inside, then I can't access the other keyup. I want to be able to display all the keyups in a sentence or alert.

Comment: Something like that ? 

`<script>

    let myPhone;
    let myMail;

    $( "#phone" ).keyup(function() {
      myPhone = $(this).val();
      alert(myPhone + " - " + myMail);
    });

    $( "#email" ).keyup(function() {
      myMail = $(this).val();
      alert(myPhone + " - " + myMail);
    });
    
</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to alert both values even if the event isn't yet triggered. You should

1. Create a global access to the email and phone variables, could also be an object
2. Attach the event first
3. Run myValidation() after both events are triggered, adding a flag to do so;
4. Alert the values from the global scope

Following your code, you can:

```js
//Create global variables
var phone, email;

//Create function to attach events
function setEvents(){
    //switched to change event
    $( "#phone" ).change(function() {
      phone = $(this).val();
      
      myValidation(); //call after
    });
    
    $( "#email" ).change(function() {
      email = $(this).val();
      
      myValidation(); //call after
    });
}

//Prepare myValidation() function to call after both events are triggered
function myValidation() {
    //Check if phone and email exists before alerting from the global scope
    if(phone && email) alert(phone + " - " + email);
}

setEvents(); //initiate function to attach events to element
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="phone">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
```

But like others said, you can just directly get `$(element).val()` without any variables at play; but we are following from your logic which I think is much better for a direct answer to the problem.

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I needed. I so understand this now. Yes, I can see that you made the myValidation() class below , yet called it above. My mind was just unable to see that. But as I read your answer, I am able to see that now. Thank you Abana Clara!

Comment: @Gosi I did not call it above. Because the `change` event will be triggered way after the entire js file is executed from top to bottom. What's happening here is that the `myValidation()` was just prepared to be called when the event is triggered

Comment: But `myValidation()` occurs only at 3. The change events occur at 2 , yet it called in a function at 3. How is that so?

Comment: @Gosi I did not call it at 3. I just worded my comment badly. You should not see this entire script be executed linearly. This is not how events work. You should understand that code inside event callbacks are executed only after the specific events are triggered

Comment: I get it now, yup that made sense Abana. "prepared to be called" made me understand it! Thank you so much!